# Strange behavior of JSON.parse() reviver function

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am using second parameter of JSON.parse() to modify the result, but I don't quite clear about the order of the function parameter and also how it work

I have read the document about the using of the reviver function (e.g https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-json.parse and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). 
From what I understand, this function would work with object, and first parameter is key or property name, second function is value or property value. What I don't understand is the return value of the function.

This is what it is done in example

```js
var obj1 = '{"a":1, "b":42}';
let text = JSON.parse(obj1, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'number'){
    return value * 2
    }
    else{
        return value
        }
    }
 )
 console.log(text) // {"a": 2, "b": 84}
```

This work well. But when I try to modify the code since I know all value is number already

```js
var obj1 = '{"a":1, "b":42}';
let text = JSON.parse(obj1, (key, value) =>{
                return value * 2
                })
console.log(text) // NaN
```

It is strange to me why when I delete the `return value` it doesn't work. I mean, with the function none of the value return undefined when I `value*2` it. I then try another test

```js
    var obj1 = '{"a":1, "b":42}';
    let text = JSON.parse(obj1, (key, value) => {
      if (typeof value === 'number'){
        console.log('This is in if',key, value)
        return value * 2
      }
      else{
        console.log('This is in else', key, value)
        return value
      }
    }
    )
    console.log(text)
```

Another strange thing happen when the code in `else` statement run even when it suppose not to run because the condition is incorrect. And when it run it even print out the `obj1` object, which I didn't include in the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Because it will also iterate thorough the object which is `{"a":1, "b":42}`.It will start from most nested level and then will go the original value itself which is `{"a":1, "b":42}`.

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> If a reviver is specified, the value computed by parsing is transformed before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties **(beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself)** are individually run through the reviver

By the way you can shorten your function.

```js
var obj1 = '{"a":1, "b":42}';
let text = JSON.parse(obj1, (_, value) => value * 2 || value)
 console.log(text)
```

Comment: But I mean, why do you need the `value` part when it should be enough to write `(_, value) => value * 2`